# When are curves smooth in a pencil $C_{(s:t)}=\{sF+tG\}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, plane-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $C_1=V(F),C_2=V(G)$ be smooth curves in $\Bbb{P}_{\Bbb{C}}^2$ and consider the pencil of curves $C_{(s:t)}=sF+tG$ for $(s:t)\in\Bbb{P}^1$.

I'm trying to prove/disprove that $C_{(s:t)}$ is smooth for all but finitely many $(s:t)\in\Bbb{P}^1$.

If $F,G\in \Bbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$, the conditions for $P\in C_{(s:t)}$ to be singular is that $(sF+tG)_X$, $(sF+tG)_Y$, $(sF+tG)_Z$ and $sF+tG$ are all zero at $P$.

This looks like a very strong condition, so it really looks like there can't be many $(s:t)$ that makes the four terms above be zero for all $P$.

But I'm having real difficulty proving this. I've tried simple cases, for example when $F$ is quadratic and $G$ is linear, and the result was clear, but more general examples looked really complicated.

I know I'm doing a brute-force approach, and if there's a better on, I'd be happy to know.

Comment: " for example when $F$ is quadratic and $G$ is linear" If $F$ and $G$ are not homogeneous of the same degree, then $sF+tG$ will not be homogeneous unless $s$ or $t$ is zero. So you don't get a pencil of curves that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider the set

$$Problem:=\{((x:y:z),(s:t)) \in \mathbb{P}^2\times \mathbb{P}^1\;|\; (x: y: z) \text{ is a singular point of }V(sF+tG) \}.$$

This is a closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^2\times \mathbb{P}^1$, and so it is a projective variety. It has an obvious projection $Problem \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1, ((x:y:z),(s:t)) \mapsto (s: t).$ Try to show that the image of the projection consists of finitely many points only (use projectivity, and topology of $\mathbb{P}^1$).

Comment: Pavel, since the varieties involved are projective, the map $\text{Problem}\to\Bbb{P}^1$ is closed, so the image is closed. If I can show the image is not the whole $\Bbb{P}^1$, then we're done. Right?

Comment: Yes, precisely. So now it is just a question of finding a point on $\mathbb{P}^1$ not in the image.

Comment: So it looks like the hypothesis of $V(F), V(G)$ being smooth is not necessary

Comment: Well, I guess one of them should be (if both $V(F),$ $V(G)$ were cusps, say $X^2Z-Y^3$ and $2X^2Z-Y^3$, the pencil migh be a family of cusps). But the fact that only one of them is needed non-singular is not surprising: If $V(F), V(G)$ are non-singular and $C_{(s: t)}$ is one of the singular members of the family, the conclusion about only finitely many singular members should be equally true when $V(G)$ gets replaced by $C_{(s: t)}$ since the pencil they determine is the same.